# Create separate AppDomain for my plug-in on revit

Tags: c#, revit-api, revit

Dears,
when creating a Windows app, you can use AppDomain.CurrentDomain anywhere in any DLL in my app but when creating a plugin for Revit, the domain always Revit domain and I don't know how to replace it with my app domain, also I can't use assembly load for the same reason.

Revit search for DLL in his path, not my app path even if I give him my path, he ignores it.

How can I solve these problems? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No Revit API code can be executed anywhere except within the AppDomain created by Revit itself, the thread supplied by Revit, and the valid Revit API context provided by the various events defined by the Revit API.

I discussed this recently in the Revit API discussion forum on [how to execute an `IExternalCommand` in another `AppDomain`](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/how-to-excute-an-iexternalcommand-in-another-appdomain/m-p/9221311).

In short, you cannot.

Please read the [Revit API getting started material](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#2) and understand the fundamentals of Revit add-in architecture described by the [developer guide](https://help.autodesk.com/view/RVT/2020/ENU/?guid=Revit_API_Revit_API_Developers_Guide_html).

Revit API code is only executable within a valid Revit API context.

Such a context is only available within event handlers that have been registered to respond to Revit API events, such as the external command Execute event.

All Revit events are launched within one single thread and one single AppDomain predefined by Revit.

This is not a problem, this is a fact.

There is nothing to solve.

Comment: Many thanks for your fast replay
some was named jusho have video demonstrate how we can invoke our external commands
it works for only one dll
if my app consist of more than one dll, its not working because revit domain search for these dlls in his own folders
i have some search on internet to bind all those dlls to anther domain but i didn't figure how to do that in revit 
is this not posible also?

Comment: The architecture described above applies always, under all circumstances. You can of course work around it by implementing a Revit add-in that reads a byte stream from some other source, e.g., from the Internet, and injects that into a placeholder external command event handler executing within a valid Revit API context.

Comment: Many thanks for your great support and Happy new year

Comment: Thank you for your appreciation and Happy New Year to you too!